# ComboBoxViewerCellEditor Display String inside List Of Objects

Tags: java, swt, jface

Problem Statement: Get the getter and setter of a class declared as a collection in another class

**DataModel**

```
Public Class Person{
 String firstName;
 String lastName;
 Collection<Address> allAddresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
 getFirstName(){..}
 getLastName{..}
 getContacts{....}
}

Public Class Address{
 String Street;
 String City;
 getCity(){..};
 getStreet(){..};
}
```

**TableViewer Contents**

```
personTableViewer.setInput(//lsit of Persons from Database)
columViewer.setLabelProvider{...
...
}
DropDownInTable dot = new DropDownInTable(valcol.getViewer());
columnViewe.setEditingSupport(dot)
```

**DropDownClass**

```
private ComboBoxViewerCellEditor cellEditor=null;
potected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
  //element here is person Object.I need setINput as getAddress().getCity()
  //if there was way to make element as address Object It would be great
    cellEditor.setInput(element.getAddress)
    return cellEditor;
}
```

If there is way to force element to be address object or retrieve addresses it would be great any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setLabelProvider` call to set a label provider that gets the string for each object in the collection. The label provider would be something like:

```
class CollectionLabelProvider extends LabelProvider
{
  @Override
  public String getText(Object element)
  {
    // 'element' is an object from the collection

    CollectionEntry entry = (CollectionEntry)element;

    return entry.getString();
  }
}
```

replace 'CollectionEntry' with the class in your collection.

Comment: Greg thank you for reply. However I see collectionEntry is in hibernate package I might be able to better explain situation by editing the question

Comment: tried it throws an error like this
com.example.e4.rcp.tables.OrgDetails cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry